# Question on mathematical induction which involves factorial and inequality.

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

[image: Markscheme from the question]

The image shows the mark scheme for mathematical induction question. 
I do not understand how you know $(2k)!$ is more than $(k!)^2  2^k$ ($2$ lines below consider $P(k+1)$.
Can someone explain it to me please?

Comment: That is the induction hypothesis!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is  the induction hypothesis, we assume $P(k)$ is true: that is $(2k)! > (k!)^2 2^k$ is true.